# Unity AdMob iOS SDK linker error

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, admob

I am struggling to compile the iOS AdMob SDK in xcode.
After whole day of solving the "Module GoogleMobileAds.framework can not be  found" problem, I finally made it through successful compile, but now the linker fails.
These are the errors it displays:
[image]

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:   "__kmsetForChildren",
>   referenced from:
>         _Admob__kmsetForChildren_m1210033255 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>
> "__kmisInterstitialReady", referenced from:
>         _Admob__kmisInterstitialReady_m1074969033 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Admob__kmisInterstitialReady_m1074969033)

and others..
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out It was plugins conflict and AdmobAPI folder mistakenly placed in Assets/Plugins project folder.
I had AdinCube android only plugin which was conflicting the iOS AdMob plugin somehow.
Removing the Plugins/Android folder (which contained the AdinCube sdk) and Plugins/AdmobAPI folder solved the xcode build problem